# Xamarin.Android 8.1 not work with .NET Framework 4.7.1

Tags: c#, xamarin.android

I started a project with Xamarin.Android 8.1 and i add a class library with .NET Framework 4.7.1. but when i referenced to my class library, my Android project cant use from classes that exists in my class library.

```
MyClassLibrary > .NET Framework 4.7.1
MyAndroidProject > Xamarin 8.1
    Add Reference > MyClassLibrary
```

In Code:

```
using MyClassLibrary;
MyClass c;
Error: The type or namespace name 'MyClass' could not be found (are 
you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

I do:

1. Clean Solution
2. Remove Debug Folders
3. Rebuild Solution
4. Close VS 2017
5. Test with a new project in other solution

But not work!!!

Please help me. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolve this problem by update these packages from NuGet (in this time to prerelease version):

```
Xamarin.Android.Arch.Core.Common
Xamarin.Android.Arch.Lifecycle.Common
Xamarin.Android.Arch.Lifecycle.Runtime
```